# React native expo app: how to create redirect_uri

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, authorization

I am new to react native, and now creating an application, with authorization via third-party provider (Identity Blitz).
The browser opens (via expo-web-browser), the user is authorized and must be returned back to the application, passing special tokens.

To return to the application, I need to generate a redirect_uri, like (exactly this, using https) "redirect_uri"="https://app.example.com/oauth2redirect/example-provider"

Could anyone explain me what and how to insert in place of "app.example.com" and "example-provider"?

After reading the documentation on the Expo and React-Native site, I did not find a solution. There is no documentation for the provider I use

I tired AuthSession.makeRedirectUri() from expo-auth-session but because I'm developing with expo go app, it returns path like exp://"some-strange-string".honestelf."port".exp.direct, and that's not what I need